# vert.x spring boot swagger integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger, vert.x

I am trying to integrate and run spring boot vert.x and swagger together.
but I have exception

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [io.project.application.SpringConfig]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:616) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:299) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:245) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:606) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at
```

Project location here https://github.com/armdev/vertx-spring

I want to run vert.x using spring, but also integrate swagger.
When I remove swagger configuration it works well.
Any suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have done swagger configuration manually, removed Spring/Swagger integration via annotations. Works perfect.

https://github.com/armdev/vertx-spring

Comment: I want to implement Swagger-UI in Vert.X app. I have listed all routes and I want to see them in swagger-ui like in SpringBoot. I have also manually edited them in swagger-editor. So, how to open localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html from vert.x app and there to see all routers.

I read that i need to save the json from swagger-editor and to put it in src/resources. After that what?

Can you help me to implement it?

Comment: Follow this structure https://github.com/armdev/vertx-spring/blob/master/vertx-node/src/main/resources/webroot/api/swagger.json

Comment: you should manually write your swagger json or generate https://github.com/armdev/vertx-spring/tree/master/vertx-node explore this project

Comment: I have edited the json manually. After that what? Should I open it in some route? If yes, how to make it?